# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Methods that makes a call to the service written in java

```
 resendRealTime(envelopeIds: String[]): Observable<String> 
  {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json' });
     console.log(envelopeIds);
    let json = JSON.stringify({envelopeIds: envelopeIds});
    console.log(json);
     return this.http.post<String>(`${AppSettings.baseServiceUrl}/docusign/resendRealTime`, json, {headers: headers} )
    .catch((error: Response) => this.handleErrors(error));
}
```

Method that calls the above method

```
 resendEnvelope() {
   let envelopeIdsArray = new Array<String>();
  console.log('Inside resend');
  this.envelopeIdsHolder.envelopeIds.forEach(function (item) {
      envelopeIdsArray.push(item);
  })

  this.backendService.resendRealTime(envelopeIdsArray).subscribe( result => console.log(`Service resend envelope returned '${result}'`));
}
```

Java Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resendRealTime", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<?> resendRealTime( @RequestBody EnvelopeIds envelopeIds) {
    log.info("envleopeIds : " + envelopeIds);
    System.out.println("inside resendrealtime");
    SwpDocuSignBulkLoader.resendRealTime(envelopeIds);

    return  new ResponseEntity<String>("ok", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'm using here HTTPCLIENTMODULE in the angular to make a call, but here it's returing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined". There is no problem in the java end where it's returning ResponseEntity

Comment: backend.service.ts:134 Error: OK
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:231)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:130
Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:104
Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:130

Comment: Above is the error that I'm receiving

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Observables in angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables),

```
const observ = this.http.post(...)
const handler = ovserv.share() // in case you want to handle it by yourself
handler.subscribe((results) => {}, (err) => {}, (complete) => {})
return handler
```

What happend is that `Observable.catch` returns null and afterward you tried to "subscribe" to an undefined object.

Comment: not sure whey the observable.catch returns null, I have tried the below where it's just returning the response and I still see the issue.
                                                                       
   @RequestMapping(value = "/resendRealTime", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<?> resendRealTime( @RequestBody EnvelopeIds envelopeIds) {
    log.info("envleopeIds : " + envelopeIds);   

    return  new ResponseEntity<String>("ok", HttpStatus.OK);
}

Comment: The issue is in your Client side and not in your server side, you can verify that using the Chrome inspect tool. (you can track the network traffic on your page)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to angular. Why is it going to catch here?. Since there is no issue from the response from the service

Comment: @Tharun, did you solve the issue? I am facing a similar issue!